# How to remotely run a desktop/GUI applications via SSH?

Tags: ssh, python, gui

I have an Ubuntu Desktop machine. If I open terminal and type:

```
chromium-browser
```

I can launch Chromium
Or for example can execute this pythons script

```
import pyautogui, sys
im2 = pyautogui.screenshot('/var/www/my_screenshot.png')
```

So if I type

```
python /var/www/python/m1.py
```

It makes a screenshot.

However, if I connect to this machine via SSH and try to execute the same commands (does not matter as an ordinary user or as root), the commands do not work.
So I can't remotely run Chromium (no error in Putty, but browser just do not run) and I can't make the screenshot remotely, I see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/python/m1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui, sys
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 149, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

So how to run applications/scripts via SSH so that they work exactly as if I run them from terminal of the machine?

Comment: Do you want the GUI windows to be displayed on the server's monitor or on the client's monitor (from where you run `ssh`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can run GUI applications on your local desktop when connected via ssh to another machine by adding these flags:

```
ssh -o ForwardX11=yes -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ForwardX11Trusted=yes username@ip
```

forward simply tells the vm to forward its display output to your local display.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`ssh REMOTE_IP "DISPLAY=:0 nohup chromium-browser"`where `REMOTE_IP` is the machine you are connecting to.

Comment: for showing the output in the current monitor try 

ssh -XYC $REMOTE_IP nohup chromium-browser